# How to search for same ID with different test results in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My goal is to write a code to find the same ID that has different test results. Table 1 contains many rows, but I added these 4 rows as an example. I know my code is not correct, but what would be the correct way of obtaining this specific information? (see Desired Goal below)
I hope my question makes sense, but feel free to comment if it is not clear.

Table 1:

| ID | TEST_RESULT | DIAGNOSIS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | POSITIVE | X78 |
| 2 | NEGATIVE | U98 |
| 3 | POSITIVE | U98 |
| 4 | NFEGATIVE | Y55 |

Desired Goal:

| ID | TEST_RESULT | DIAGNOSIS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | POSITIVE | X78 |
| 2 | NEGATIVE | U98 |

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ID <> ' ' AND TEST_RESULT= NEGATIVE AND TEST_RESULT = POSITIVE;
```

Comment: Are "POSITIVE" and "NEGATIVE" the only `TEST_RESULT` values?

Comment: Yes, they are the only TEST_RESULT values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a sub-query to count how many `POSITIVE` and `NEGATIVE` results each ID has and then use its results in your filtering:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE id IN (
              SELECT ID
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY ID
              HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN test_result = 'POSITIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
                     AND  
                     SUM(CASE WHEN test_result = 'NEGATIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0   
             );
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ba7e2c/7)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `EXISTS` operator to check if another row with the same `id`, but different `test_result` values exists in the table.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM results r1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM results r2
    WHERE r1.id = r2.id AND r1.test_result != r2.test_result
)
```

Output

| id | test_result | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | POSITIVE | X78 |
| 2 | NEGATIVE | U98 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d4c78ecf12981cf9b69bd004c5285885)*

Answer (score 2):

```
select   ID 
        ,TEST_RESULT    
        ,DIAGNOSIS
from    (
         select   *
                 ,min(TEST_RESULT) over w as mn
                 ,max(TEST_RESULT) over w as mx
         from     t
         window   w as (partition by ID)
        ) t
where    mn <> mx
```

| ID | TEST_RESULT | DIAGNOSIS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | POSITIVE | X78 |
| 2 | NEGATIVE | U98 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=18babc7d752555da7a2573b055f9faaf)